# What does the phrase "not if I have to" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

It's from the second episode of the first season of *Breaking Bad*.

> And just so you know, my brother-in-law is a DEA agent...
>
> ...and I will not hesitate to call him. **Not if I have to**. Understood?
>
> This is your one and only warning.

Does that mean that the person won't call the agent, but will call if she has to. I am confused.

Comment: Having said "I will not hesitate to call him" the bolded sentence can be expanded to "I will not hesitate to call him if I have to."

Comment: I will not hesitate to call him, if I have to [call him].

Comment: Thanks, but that is not actually what I cannot get. I cannot get what "not" is there for. I can't get the phrase as a whole.

Comment: I read the "not" as a restatement of the "not hesitate" part of the first statement.

Comment: I will not hesitate to call him, not [hesitate, that is,] if I have to [call him].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...and I will not hesitate to call him. Not if I have to. Understood?

"Not if I have to" is a callback to the previous statement about calling his brother-in-law. It should be understood as "I will not hesitate if I have to call him".

It is a threat that he will only make the call if *he feels compelled to* by the other person's actions.